# How to get the source of Selected image using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<li class="k-tile k-state-selected" data-type="f" data-uid="504c365a-fd54-4a9f-adc2-c217ce4dc8fc" role="option" aria-selected="false">
    <div class="k-thumb">
        <img class="k-image" alt="1.jpg" style="" src="http://doelbewust.nl/img/doelbewust_logo.png">
    </div>
    <strong>1.jpg</strong>
    <span class="k-filesize">206.97 KB</span>
</li>
```

I want to get the source of a image when I click inside li element.
Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('li.k-state-selected').on("click", function(){
  var src=$(this).find("img").attr("src");
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u94en71g/1/)

Answer (score 2):

> *I want to get the source of a image whn i clicked inside li elemen*

```
$('li').click(function(){
   alert($(this).find('img').attr('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
$('li .k-tile').click(function(){//only the li with .k-title class
     $(this).find('img .k-image').attr('src'); //only the image with .k-image class
});
```

Comment: should  be `li k-tile` for li with .k-title class

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on li, showing img src. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/d93jrk71/)

```
$('.k-tile').on('click', function() {
    var img= $('.k-image').attr('src');
    alert(img);
})
```